# How to apply a complex style to the selection of a Select2 component?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

Today I ran into a seemingly simple styling task when using the Select2 plugin, but it seems that the thing I want to achieve is more difficult than I thought. Here's what I want to do:

The user should be able to choose a contact from a dropdown menu. Each contact entry should be displayed as the contact's profile picture and some data next to it. When collapsed, the dropdown should display the selected contact (i.e. the selected contact's profile picture and some data next to it) with a "dropdown triangle" next to it. In the expanded state, the dropdown should additionally display the other contacts, each with profile pic and data. Put simply, I want to do templating as described in the "Templating" example on [the select2 example page](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), just with a more complex layout (profile picture on the left plus three stacked lines of text right next to the picture).

I managed to apply the desired style to the **results** by using the `formatResult` select2 option, using a format function which wraps the image and data in styled div elements (note that I use Twitter Bootstrap's 'media' css class for styling):

```
function formatContactResult(item) {
 if(!item.id)
    return "No contact selected";

 var contact = JSON.parse(item.text);
 return "<div class='media'><a class='pull-left' href='#'><img style='margin-top: 5px;' class='media-object' data-src='holder.js/64x64' src='" + contact.thumbUrl + "' /></a><div class='media-body' style='font-size: 11px;'><strong>" + contact.displayName + "</strong><br />" + contact.jobTitle + "</div></div>"
};
```

My problem: I can't figure out how to apply a complex layout like this to the **selection**. I'm aware of the `formatSelection` option, but the return value of the `formatSelection` function is wrapped in a `span` element which is not an appropriate wrapper for complex layouts. Although I know it's not valid, I tried to apply the same layout function I mentioned above, but that expectedly led to weird results (the desired layout being pushed far to the right).

Does anyone have an clue on how I can achieve the described layout with select2?

If it's of any interest, I'm using the Select2 plugin with Knockout.js and Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out - the problem was that all `div` elements contained in the `select2-choice` component are absolutely positioned and styled in `select2.css`:

```
.select2-container .select2-choice div {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    [...]
}
```

This style is used to render the "dropdown triangle" of the dropdown box, which happens to be a `div` element. Unfortunately, the triangle `div` doesn't have an own CSS class name which should be used to style it.

So as a workaround, I created a new CSS class and applied it to the `div` elements I wanted to render inside of the `select2-choice` component. The idea is to override the position and width attributes:

```
.innerDiv {
    position: relative !important; 
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: By any chance, have you done any styling of the text with select2? I have been trying to change the font-size property, but even after editing the CSS, I cannot get a handle on the text inside the select2 containers that show up in the drop-down state. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I have been able to style text. For me it works by just adding `font-size: 10px !important;` to the `.innerDiv` CSS class mentioned above. Of course you have to check whether your text style is overridden by any other (nested) element which also may have !important style definitions, or inline style definitions.